# CiviCRM Public forms not respecting theme

Tags: theme

I am using Drupal 7.4x and civicrm 4.6.10.

For some reason when my civi forms load on the front end they often load with the administration theme (seven) and then if I refresh, it will load with my front end theme (Zurb-Foundation 4).

In appearance settings, I have the civicrm admin theme set to 'SEVEN' and the public theme set to 'Default'

Any idea on what might be causing this?

UPDATE:
I noticed that every time caches are cleared the initial load of the civicrm public page will use the "SEVEN" theme but the sub-sequential loads will use my default theme.